# "Welcome back" bar colour scheme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is what I got on top of my screen when I first logged in:

[image]

My eyesight isn't good, but I believe that's light yellow over light grey (mostly #FFF7CE over #F8FAF7), which is to say it's hardly visible at all.

In Firefox 3, Vista (you only get to choose some things in the business world...)

Comment: yep definitely a bug. will fix soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.